# Вложенные запросы или параметры в SQL

Tags: sql, psql

Есть sql запрос Select с множеством подзапросов.
Часть подзапросов использует в условии where одинаковый подзапрос типа

```
D."Date" = (select max(D."Date") from ... where ...)
```

Как сделать, чтобы не повторять одинаковое условие, так как скорость падает пропорционально количеству таких подзапросов?

Comment: Использовать CTE.

Comment: СТЕ не могут быть вложенными(

Comment: Не понял фразы. Где я говорю о ВЛОЖЕННЫХ CTE? А вот использовать уже определённые выше CTE им никто не запрещает.

Comment: Спасибо всё получилось с CTE